# Can't make my stepper motor run with AccelStepper Library

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm relatively new to arduino thus need your help to figure out why my stepper motor doesn't move while trying to change its direction using AccelStepper library.

Actually I could make my stepper motor rotate in one direction, but while changing the code to make it rotate clockwise and counterclockwise, the motor doesn't move at all.
Here is my code:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

int pos=16000;
AccelStepper stepper(1,4,5);

void setup() {
stepper.setMaxSpeed(6400);
stepper.setSpeed(6400);
stepper.moveTo(pos);
}

void loop() {
if (stepper.distanceToGo() == 0)
{   
  stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);  
  pos = -pos;  
  stepper.moveTo(pos);  
}
   stepper.runSpeed();
}
```

Will appreciate any help you can give me :)

Comment: I think is more useful for you to post this question in the appropriate section of StackOverflow: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Thanks, I've already posted my question to this group :)